# Drawing an image onto a canvas in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I'm looking to draw an image onto a canvas for my HTML page using a separate Javascript file.  The HTML I have thus far is fine, my problem seems to lie within the script.  This is what I have currently:

```
    function doFirst(){
    var x = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas = x.getContext('2d');

    var pic = new image();
    pic.src="http://i1273.photobucket.com/albums/y418/Cloudtwonj/Backgroundtest_zps2a6a6b51.jpeg";
    pic.addEventListener("load", function(){canvas.drawImage(pic,0,0,x.width,x.height)}, false);
}
window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

Can anyone tell me what I might have done wrong or forgot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor is `Image`, not `image` - capitalization matters!

```
var pic = new Image();
```

```js
    function doFirst() {
      var x = document.getElementById('canvas');
      canvas = x.getContext('2d');

      var pic = new Image();
      pic.src = "http://i1273.photobucket.com/albums/y418/Cloudtwonj/Backgroundtest_zps2a6a6b51.jpeg";
      pic.addEventListener("load", function() {
        canvas.drawImage(pic, 0, 0, x.width, x.height)
      }, false);
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote it.  I have no idea why it's downvoted, and I'm unable to upvote until I reach a reputation of 15.

Comment: I wonder if it was the other answerer, who decided to give a revenge downvote. :/ Well, thanks for accepting the correct answer.